# Asyncktask sending two param to the client

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code to send a param to a client server and get a response.
now I have two params of  String type to sendI realy confused  I what  the code would be ?

```
protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... data)
    { 

     JSONObject json = data[0]; 

     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000); 
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build()); 
     JSONObject jsonResponse = null; 

     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url); 
     String resFromServer = ""; 

     try 
     { 
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString()); 

     post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

      post.setEntity(se); 

      HttpResponse response; 
      response = client.execute(post); 
      resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 

     Log.i("Response from server", resFromServer); 

                         } 
      catch (Exception e) 
                         { 
      e.printStackTrace();
                         } 


      return resFromServer; 

                         }
                             }
```

Comment: you want to send the params with url as get or post paremeters?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create JSONObject and put those two string in it, and have to pass whole Object as a param like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("String1Key",string1);
jsonObj.put("String2Key",string2);
```

just remove the line JSONObject json = data[0] and add this
it will work

By the way if you're using doInBackground(JSONObject... data) params then pass data[0] and data[1] as a parameter in json.put

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post parameters to your urls like this

```
try {
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter_name_1", "string1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter_name_2", "string2"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
 } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
 }
```

replace parameter_name_1,parameter_name_2,string1 and string2 appropriatly

Comment: What return type would be?

Comment: it would be HttpResonse from which you can get the data

Comment: This is my onPostExecute method what datatype of result it should be protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      asyncCallback.onResponse(result);
    }